# Annoying message at every terminal opening in a new created user account

Tags: bash, terminal

I've created a new user account (with home directory) with the `$ useradd -m newuser` command. Every time I open a terminal in this new account the follow message appears just immediately before the terminal prompt:

> dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option
>   given

This doesn't happen in the (only) other one account. It is an Ubuntu distro and I don't have local config files such as `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`. All variables and configs are sourced from `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian based systems (including Ubuntu), don't use `useradd`. In fact, that's the first thing [its man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/useradd.8.html) mentions:

> useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
>          administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

So, just use `adduser newuser` and everything will work as expected. To do the same thing with `useradd`, you would need:

```
useradd -d /home/newuser -m -s /bin/bash newuser
```

But you'd also need to create the user's group and add them to it and just forget it. Use `adduser`.